# regionprops detects only one component, while there are multiple white regions in the BW image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am a beginner in image processing, I am trying to use the `regionprops` function, however I only get one value whenever I use it, even thought the image has 20 objects (cells) in it.

Here is the code I am working on in MATLAB:

```
    close all 
    clc
    clear all
    control = {};
    test={};
    se90 = strel('line',8,90);
    se0 = strel('line',8,0);
    fudgeFactor = 1.7;
    seD = strel('diamond',1);
    avgfilter =fspecial('average');% average filter
    location_control = '\\tsclient\c\cell_morphology\control\';
    list_control=dir([location_control, '*.tif']);
    for k = 1:1
        thisfig = figure();
        control=[control,double(imread([location_control list_control(k).name]))];
        con{k} = uint8(control{k});
        BandW{k} = rgb2gray(con{k}); % turn the image from RGB into gray 
        %smoothing:
        lowhigh{k} = imadjust(BandW{k},stretchlim(BandW{k}),[]);
        fltcon{k} = imfilter(lowhigh{k},avgfilter);
        [~,threshold] = edge(lowhigh{k},'sobel');
        BWs{k} = edge(fltcon{k},'sobel',threshold * fudgeFactor);%binary gradient mask
        % dilation:
        BWsdil{k} = imdilate(BWs{k},[se90 se0]);
        %filling gapes
        BWdfill{k} = imfill(BWsdil{k},'holes');
        % removing irregular cells:
        BWcleaned{k} = bwpropfilt(BWdfill{k},'Perimeter',12);
        BWcleaned2{k} = bwpropfilt(BWdfill{k},'Eccentricity',2); % detects elongated cells 
        zerones{k} =  im2bw(BWcleaned{k}); % convert the matrix to 1s and 0s. 
        revzerones{k} =  1- zerones{k}; 
        clean{k} = BWdfill{k} .* revzerones{k}+ BWcleaned2{k};
        %smooth objects
        BWfinal{k} = imerode(clean{k},seD);
        BWfinal{k} = imerode(BWfinal{k},seD);
        %clean borders:
        BWnobord{k} = imclearborder(BWfinal{k},4);
        %Visualization of the Segmentation
        final{k} = labeloverlay(lowhigh{k},BWnobord{k});
        imshow(final{k});
        title(sprintf('image %d',k));
        [~, num{k}] = bwlabel(pdilate{k}); %counts the number of cells in image k 
        pdilate{k} = imdilate(BWnobord{k},[se90 se0]);
%reginprops code: 
        charc{k} = regionprops('table',pdilate{k},'Area','MinorAxisLength','MajorAxisLength', 'Perimeter');
        Areas{k} = [charc{k}.Area];
        Perim{k} = [charc{k}.Perimeter];
        MJax{k} = [charc{k}.MajorAxisLength];
        MNax{k} = [charc{k}.MinorAxisLength];
  
    end
```

I tried different methods to make it work but it only returns one value each time, in this case what could be done?
[image: this is one of the images I am working on, it is a lower resolution because of limits on the website, there are 10 images in total.]

This is one of the images I am working on, it is a lower resolution because of limits on the website, there are 10 images in total that is why I am using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you passed an image of a type other than `logical` to `regionprops`. From the `clean{k} = BWdfill{k} .* revzerones{k}+ BWcleaned2{k};` line onward, the image is converted to double. So `regionprops` assumes that the image contains region labels (like [`stats = regionprops(L,properties)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)). But since all non-zero pixels have a value of 1, it detects only one region and returns its properties. Try:

```
charc{k} = regionprops('table',pdilate{k}, 'Image');
imshow(charc{k}.Image{1})
```

[image]

To fix this you can either convert `clean` to `logical`:

```
clean{k} = logical(BWdfill{k} .* revzerones{k}+ BWcleaned2{k});
```

, or covert the image passed to `regionprops`:

```
charc{k} = regionprops('table',pdilate{k}>0,'Area','MinorAxisLength','MajorAxisLength', 'Perimeter');
```